# In Nuxt.js, load a simple Google map

Tags: vue.js, google-maps, nuxt.js

I am doing this successfully on another project and I do not understand at all, why I am getting an empty div here instead of a map. The map should render here:

```
<template>
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div style="height: 500px; width: 500px;" ref="map"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the code:

```
head() {
    return {
        title: 'Properties',
        script: [{
            src: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX",
            hid: "map", 
            defer: true,
        }]
    }
},

mounted(){
    const mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(43.758773, -79.391785),
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    };

    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, mapOptions);
    const position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(43.758773, -79.391785)
    const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({ position })
    marker.setMap(map)
},
```

Comment: Hi. If you need , I will share my yandex map code.

Comment: @izzatullokanoatov please do

Comment: @FrancisManojFernnado Hi. Have you tried using https://vue-yandex-maps.github.io/en/guide/#installing ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `mapOptions` object change `center` to `center: { lat: 43.758773, lng: -79.391785 }`

You can reference this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal